# Contour plot in Python importing txt table file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a contour plot like:

[image: contour]

Using a table of data like 3 columns in a txt file, with a long number of lines.

Using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate

data = np.loadtxt(r'dataa.txt')

a = [data[:,0]]
b = [data[:,1]]
n = [data[:,2]]

x = np.asarray(a)
y = np.asarray(b)
z = np.asarray(n)

print "x = ", x
print "y = ", y
print "z = ", z

fig=plt.figure()

CF = contour(x,y,z,colors = 'k')

plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I don't know why, it is not working. Python gives me the right axes for the values that I am expecting to see, but in the graph is just a blank and I know that it is importing the data in right way because it shows me my values before the plot.

Example of table: (the diference is because my table has 90000 lines)
[image]

Using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate

N = 1000 #number of points for plotting/interpolation

x, y, z = np.genfromtxt(r'dataa.txt', unpack=True)

xi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), N)
yi = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), N)
zi = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')

fig = plt.figure()
plt.contour(xi, yi, zi)
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.show()
```

Ive got this result:
[image]
I think I've got the advices wrongly.

Comment: Are `x` and `y` regularly spaced?  If not, you'll need to interpolate to make a contour plot.  If so, you can use them to populate a 2d array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Followup from my comment... first, I would replace all these lines:

```
data = np.loadtxt(r'dataa.txt')

a = [data[:,0]]
b = [data[:,1]]
n = [data[:,2]]

x = np.asarray(a)
y = np.asarray(b)
z = np.asarray(n)
```

With:

```
x, y, z = np.genfromtxt(r'dataa.txt', unpack=True)
```

Your original code is adding an extra axis at the front, since `[data[:,0]]` is a list of arrays with one element.  The result is that `x.shape` will be `(1, N)` instead if `(N,)`.  All of this can be done automatically using the last line above, or you could just use the same `data` loading and say:

```
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
z = data[:,2]
```

since those slices will give you an array back.

However, you're not quite done, because `plt.contour` expects you to give it a 2d array for `z`, not a 1d array of values.  Right now, you seem to have `z` values at given `x, y` points, but `contour` expects you to give it a 2d array, like an image.

Before I can answer that, I need to know how `x` and `y` are spaced.  If regularly, you can just populate an array pretty easily.  If not regularly, you basically have to interpolate before you can make a contour plot.

To do the interpolation, use

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate

N = 1000 #number of points for plotting/interpolation

x, y, z = np.genfromtxt(r'dataa.txt', unpack=True)

xi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), N)
yi = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), N)
zi = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')

fig = plt.figure()
plt.contour(xi, yi, zi)
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I've made some alterations in my question using your coment... But it still didnt solve my problem, I think I've got it wrong, but I have a right line shape, what is better than before that I had blank. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like probably the problem is in the interpolation.  Try fiddling with the `method`, or `N`.  One thing you can do to test things is `plt.scatter(x, y, c=z)` which does a scatter plot of your points, and colors them by the `z` value.

Comment: This helped me! Thanks! If you dont mind me asking, how do I know the value that I should assign for N?

Comment: @Victor, `N` is effectively the plotting *resolution* so it will depend on the spacing and smoothness of your data.  Think of it as the number of pixels to use to display an image: more will give you more accurate curves, but fewer will run faster and look simpler.

Answer (score 4):

The code below worked for me:

```
import scipy.interpolate    
import numpy as np  

N = 500 #number of points for plotting/interpolation    
x, y, z = np.genfromtxt(r'data.dat', unpack=True)
xll = x.min();  xul = x.max();  yll = y.min();  yul = y.max()

xi = np.linspace(xll, xul, N)
yi = np.linspace(yll, yul, N)
zi = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')

contours = plt.contour(xi, yi, zi, 6, colors='black')
plt.clabel(contours, inline=True, fontsize=7)
plt.imshow(zi, extent=[xll, xul, yll, yul], origin='lower', cmap=plt.cm.jet, alpha=0.9)
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y$')
plt.clim(0, 1)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```